# Copy DatePicker For Customization

Tags: c#, xaml, datepicker, customization, windows-phone-8.1

My goal is to customize a DatePickerPage, creating my own with copying xaml and cs from phone.codeplex.com ([Windows Phone Toolkit DatePickerPage](http://phone.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.WP8/DateTimePickers/DatePickerPage.xaml)).

I created a class named CustomDatepickerPage which works the same way as indicated in the source, but I have a problem in the constructor of my class, when I have to set the LoopingSelectors DataSources:

```
     public CustomDatepickerPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Hook up the data sources
            PrimarySelector.DataSource = new YearDataSource();
            SecondarySelector.DataSource = new MonthDataSource();
            TertiarySelector.DataSource = new DayDataSource();

            InitializeDateTimePickerPage(PrimarySelector, SecondarySelector, TertiarySelector);
        }
```

In fact, I can't initialize the 3 DataSources, Visual Studio telling me that I can't access due to protection level.

I don't know how to do to get these DataSources.

Thanks for your help.

Here is the full code for the CustomDatepickerPage:

XAML:

```
    <primitives:DateTimePickerPageBase
    x:Class="MyNamespace.CustomDatepickerPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
    xmlns:primitives="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Primitives;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit">
    <primitives:DateTimePickerPageBase.Resources>
        <controls:DateTimePickerResources x:Key="DateTimePickerResources"/>
        <ExponentialEase x:Key="Ease" EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
    </primitives:DateTimePickerPageBase.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisibilityStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Open">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="PlaneProjection"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="RotationX"
                            From="-50"
                            To="0"
                            Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Closed">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="PlaneProjection"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="RotationX"
                            To="90"
                            Duration="0:0:0.2"
                            EasingFunction="{StaticResource Ease}"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Grid.Projection>
            <PlaneProjection x:Name="PlaneProjection"/>
        </Grid.Projection>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- SystemTray placeholder -->
        <Rectangle
            x:Name="SystemTrayPlaceholder"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Height="32"/>
        <!-- Title -->
        <TextBlock
            x:Name="HeaderTitle"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Text="{Binding DatePickerTitle, Source={StaticResource DateTimePickerResources}}"
            FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"
            FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"
            Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
            Margin="24,16,24,24"/>
        <!-- LoopingSelectors -->
        <Grid
            Grid.Row="2"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <primitives:LoopingSelector
                x:Name="SecondarySelector"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Width="148"
                ItemSize="148,148"
                ItemMargin="6">
                <primitives:LoopingSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                            Margin="6">
                            <TextBlock
                                Text="{Binding MonthNumber}"
                                FontSize="54"
                                FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"
                                Margin="0,-8"/>
                            <TextBlock
                                Text="{Binding MonthName}"
                                FontSize="20"
                                FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
                                Margin="0,-2"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </primitives:LoopingSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </primitives:LoopingSelector>
            <primitives:LoopingSelector
                x:Name="TertiarySelector"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Width="148"
                ItemSize="148,148"
                ItemMargin="6">
                <primitives:LoopingSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                            Margin="6">
                            <TextBlock
                                Text="{Binding DayNumber}"
                                FontSize="54"
                                FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"
                                Margin="0,-8"/>
                            <TextBlock
                                Text="{Binding DayName}"
                                FontSize="20"
                                FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
                                Margin="0,-2"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </primitives:LoopingSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </primitives:LoopingSelector>
            <primitives:LoopingSelector
                Grid.Column="2"
                x:Name="PrimarySelector"
                Width="148"
                ItemSize="148,148"
                ItemMargin="6">
                <primitives:LoopingSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                            Margin="6">
                            <TextBlock
                                Text="{Binding YearNumber}"
                                FontSize="54"
                                FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"
                                Margin="0,-8"/>
                            <TextBlock
                                Text=" "
                                FontSize="20"
                                FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
                                Margin="0,-2"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </primitives:LoopingSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </primitives:LoopingSelector>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

    <primitives:DateTimePickerPageBase.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True">
            <!--
            Due to platform restrictions, ApplicationBarIconButton.IconUri content can not come from the
            Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit assembly, so it is up to the application developer to ensure
            these resources are placed in the right location and marked as Build Action=Content. For
            convenience, platform-consistent images are included with the Toolkit installer.

            Note: ApplicationBarIconButton.Text automatically comes from the Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit
            resources (where it can be localized).
            -->
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton
                IconUri="/Toolkit.Content/ApplicationBar.Check.png"
                Text="DONE"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton
                IconUri="/Toolkit.Content/ApplicationBar.Cancel.png"
                Text="CANCEL"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </primitives:DateTimePickerPageBase.ApplicationBar>
</primitives:DateTimePickerPageBase>
```

CS:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using System.Globalization;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Primitives;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class CustomDatepickerPage : DateTimePickerPageBase
    {
       /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the DatePickerPage control.
        /// </summary>
        public CustomDatepickerPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Hook up the data sources
            PrimarySelector.DataSource = new YearDataSource();
            SecondarySelector.DataSource = new MonthDataSource();
            TertiarySelector.DataSource = new DayDataSource();

            InitializeDateTimePickerPage(PrimarySelector, SecondarySelector, TertiarySelector);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a sequence of LoopingSelector parts ordered according to culture string for date/time formatting.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>LoopingSelectors ordered by culture-specific priority.</returns>
        protected override IEnumerable<LoopingSelector> GetSelectorsOrderedByCulturePattern()
        {
            string pattern = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.ToUpperInvariant();

            //if (DateTimePickerBase.DateShouldFlowRTL())
            //{
            //    char[] reversedPattern = pattern.ToCharArray();
            //    Array.Reverse(reversedPattern);
            //    pattern = new string(reversedPattern);
            //}

            return GetSelectorsOrderedByCulturePattern(
                pattern,
                new char[] { 'Y', 'M', 'D' },
                new LoopingSelector[] { PrimarySelector, SecondarySelector, TertiarySelector });
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles changes to the page's Orientation property.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Event arguments.</param>
        protected override void OnOrientationChanged(OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (null == e)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("e");
            }

            base.OnOrientationChanged(e);
            SystemTrayPlaceholder.Visibility = (0 != (PageOrientation.Portrait & e.Orientation)) ?
                Visibility.Visible :
                Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the selectors and title flow direction.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="flowDirection">Flow direction to set.</param>
        public override void SetFlowDirection(FlowDirection flowDirection)
        {
            HeaderTitle.FlowDirection = flowDirection;

            PrimarySelector.FlowDirection = flowDirection;
            SecondarySelector.FlowDirection = flowDirection;
            TertiarySelector.FlowDirection = flowDirection;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so, it works now. For those who want to customize their own datepicker, here is the steps:

- Go to [Windows Phone Toolkit CodePlex](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest), and get files from the DateTimePickers folder in Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit. Grab DatePickerPage.xaml, DatePickerPage.xaml.cs, DateTimePickerPageBase.cs, DataSource.cs.
- Rename DatePickerPage.xaml to your chosen name
- In all the files you get, change the default namespaces to your personal namespaces
- In your Custom DatePickerPage, do not call "primitives:DateTimePickerPageBase" but the DateTimePickerPage with your personal namespace
- In order to call the actions of Validation and Cancellation, in the DateTimePickerPageBase transform the OnDoneButtonClick and OnCancelButtonClick methods into public methods to call them from your DatePickerPage.

  - And, change the PickerPageUri in your DatePicker to your newly created DatePickerPage.

And "voilà" :)

Thanks [lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357504/lisp) for your valuable contribution !

Comment: Thank you GwenGuts. I really need this control (**for WP8.1 WinRT**) but I can't make it work. Do yo have a working example? Is your solution really works in WP8.1 WinRT? (Or is it a WP8.1 Silverlight app?)

Comment: @JohnCroneh Hi, it's for a WP8.1 Silverlight app. What is exactly your problem ?

Comment: The problem is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27729182/windows-phone-8-1-winrt-custom-looping-selector

Answer (score 1):

To customize the DataPickerPage I had to copy also `DataSource.cs` and `DataTimePickerPageBase.cs` into my project and changed namespaces appropriately (and I think I also commented out some lines regarding the left-to-right flow that also called some internal method).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Did you change namespaces to your personal namespaces or did you let the Microsoft.Phone.Controls default namespaces ?

Because I added DataSource file, it compile but when i click my DatePicker, I have an exception on the SelectionChanged event in the property SelectedItem of the abstract class DataSource (can not convert YearDataSource to DataSource, but YearDataSource inherits from DataSource...).

Comment: Allright, it work better if I change the namespace of DateTimePickerPageBase to my personal namespace... I have now another problem for this custom datepicker, the appbar buttons have no event attached by default ? How it is supposed to work on the control if not ? Thanks for your help