# Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT): Custom Looping Selector

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, loopingselector

I want a custom Looping Selector for my **Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT)** and I couldn't find any solution for the moment. I want something like this:

[image]

The [Windows Phone Toolkit](https://phone.codeplex.com/) is for WP8.0 and WP8.1 Silverlight and it doesn't work for WP8.1 (WinRT) apps (And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27173851/how-to-add-a-looping-selector-to-a-windows-phone-8-1-app) is for WP8.1 Silverlight).

There are [DatePicker & TimePicker](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2d2d83/date-and-time-picker-control-in-windows-phone-8-1/) controls for WP8.1. Is there any way to custom their data or something to trick the control to my problem?

There is a [LoopingSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.loopingselector.aspx) class but it seems that it is not implemented yet.

Any solution or idea would be appreciated.

Comment: are the picker classes sealed? If not, inherit a new class from them and override the methods so that they do what you want.

Comment: How can I find if they are sealed? This is the class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn299280. It is "**public class TimePicker : Control**". So can I inherit it?

Comment: @magicandre1981, If you have time to create a working example from what you said (and answer the question), it could be great for everyone to use. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I only started watching some videos about phone development. So I'm not the person you should ask about such an example.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still need this... but there is a WinRT LoopItemsPanel project available here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mim/archive/2013/04/16/winrt-create-a-custom-itemspanel-for-an-itemscontrol.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this for an "infinite snapping date selector" if that makes sense :)

Basics:

- create a data model to display which can provide you with the next/previous elements
- have a `Canvas` as your control root (it's fast)
- call render `Loaded` and rerender on `SizeChanged`
- create a (dependency)property for selected value
- subscribe for relevant manipulation events (`ManipulationDelta`, and `*Completed`) and choose what 
  `ManipulationModes` you want to allow (translate, maybe translateintertia if you want intertia)

Render:

- render screensize/elementsize + 2 elements (maybe more)
- move them on the manipulationdelta and completed events
- if an element leaves the control boundary on one side, move the last element on that side to the other end, while changing the displayed data as well (basically if it was the last, than firstelement.getprevious)
- on manipulationcompleted find the closest element to the center, and animate everything to a 'snap' position
- and finally set your selectedvalue property to the data of the centered element

This solution with animating Canvas.Left performed well even on a first-gen Surface RT. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But could you plz provide me some codes or link to the working example? Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Sorry, this was a work project, so I can't really share the code :(

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want a copy/paste code. Would you plz create an example project? It could be great for everyone to use.