# Make ListView autoselect item in the middle

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, listview, uwp

I want a ListView to auto select the item in the middle position. The user may change the selection using scrolling throught the items (using touch/mouse/scrollbars).

I don't have any idea on how to do it. I've read about IScrollInfo, but I cannot find a good example for my case. Also, since the middle item will be selected, the user could scroll the items far enought to situate the item they want in the center.

Also, if the user taps on an item, it should scroll (with the animation) until the selected item is in the middle position (like the DateTimePicker does inside the flyouts)

Comment: I'm not clearly understood, what does it mean middle position

Comment: With the middle position I mean the ListViewItem that is situated **around the half part** of the height of the ListView (in a vertically oriented ListView)

Comment: Ok, you need something like advanced ScrollIntoView method?

Comment: I want to make something similar to a "carousel" ListView, but with no looping.

Comment: You can't really do this without implementing a custom Panel. On the other hand I described a solution previously for something like this (although it's an infinite list) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27729182/windows-phone-8-1-winrt-custom-looping-selector/29633377#29633377